# Can we measure Round trip time between two machines without using either of them?

Tags: ping, traceroute

I have two machines with IP1 and IP2 addresses. Is it possible to measure the round trip time for the packets to travel between these two machines from a machine with a different IP address?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***no you can't***

Round-trip time (RTT), also called round-trip delay, is the time required for a signal pulse or packet to travel from a specific source ***(IP1)*** to a specific destination ***(IP2)*** and back again. In this context, the source is the computer initiating the signal and the destination is a remote computer or system that receives the signal and re transmits it.

user can determine the RTT to and from an IP (Internet Protocol) address by pinging that address. The result depends on various factors including The nature of the transmission medium (copper, optical fiber ) so you can't ignore it

Comment: thanks! But, if the transmission medium is fixed to say optical fiber, can we then calculate RTT?

Comment: @re3el, you could calculate the latency of the link for that medium, but that is only a small part of RTT. There is the serialization/de-serialization delays, also fixed, but there are also unknown delays of the other layers in the networks stack, how busy is the OS for each device, plus that problem of network congestion and buffering that may, or may not, happen in the path. the RTT is variable between any two devices, and it can vary from one test to the next.

Answer (score -1):

maybe by port monitoring through their switch and capturing ping/icmp traffic between them! tracking the icmp packets and measuring RTT!!

Comment: The result of RTT depends on various factors including The nature of the transmission medium (copper, optical fiber for example ) so you can't ignore it